# Custom Domains for a Simple Web App

Tags: .htaccess, dns, hosting

I've created a really simple databaseless php application that I want to offer as a hosted solution. I've enable wildcard subdomains so that users can sign up and create a subdomain (e.g. "user.myapp.com"). However, I would like to offer the ability for my users to use a custom domain as well if they prefer. I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished by asking the user to add an A Record to their custom domain pointing to my server's IP, but I'm not sure how to handle the domain on my end once they create an A Record pointing to my server's IP.

So, say a user signs up for my service under "user.myapp.com" and then they decide they want to use a custom domain "someuser.com" instead. My specific question is — once the user adds an A Record to their domain "someuser.com" pointing to my server's IP, how do I tell my server to point that domain to "user.myapp.com"? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to first setup your server to accept requests from `someuser.com`, which is entirely different than setting up a wildcard for your server alias (e.g. `*.myapp.com`). You can have a default vhost handle all the hostnames that no other vhost is setup to handle, but then you're still left with mapping `someuser.com` to `user.myapp.com`.

Depending on how you've setup your php application, the user's going to need to enter the custom domain they've registered that they had point to your app, then you'll need to know to do that mapping internally by checking the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` server variable to see what host the request is for, and if it's for `someuser.com`, then map it to `user.myapp.com`.